# Asp.net core how to create custom route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 2 project and want to create a custom route.

Now I have a route like this

```
https://localhost:44354/Question/DisplayQuestion?idqstoinid=21
```

This route contains `domain/[controller]/[action]/{id?}`

But I want to have a route like `stackoverflow.com`

I want this :

```
domain/[controller]/[id]/title of question
```

In other words I want :

```
https://localhost:44354/Question/21/myQuestionTitle
```

Comment: Are you still facing the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class QuestionController : Controller {
 [HttpGet("{id}/{title}")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int id, string title) {

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below code for routing :

```js
[Route("Question")]
public class QuestionController : Controller 
{

 [HttpGet("{id}/{title}")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int id, string title) 
 {
  //Your Code
 }

}
```

After enter the URL like https://localhost:44301/Question/21/myQuestionTitle then you can see the view bag values on view page:

[image]

Your Controller action should be :

[image]

**References** :  [MSDN - Routing to controller actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

**Cheers !!**

Comment: it does not work and shows 404 error . How should i call link in this route?

Comment: What is your URL - I have just tried with this URL - localhost:44301/Question/21/myQuestionTitle and its perfectly working for me.   See the attached snaps, in that you can see the myQuestionTitle Value.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following modification :

Controller  use `[Route("Test/{id}/{name}")]` above the 'get' request of `Details` action

```
[Route("Test/{id}/{name}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id ,string name)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var test = await _context.TestTab
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (test == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(test);
    }
```

Index View use `asp-route-{parameter}` to pass the `id` and `name`

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bedget)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id" asp-route-name="@item.Name">Details</a> |
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

}